# proof of theorem $7$ of Some further results on ideal convergence in topological spaces Pratulananda Das

Tags: general-topology, notation, proof-explanation, uniform-spaces

[this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864112001812/1-s2.0-S0166864112001812-main.pdf?_tid=32c4d424-9b8c-11e6-818c-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1477493893_2de85ffc3453abfdf9cbed979c343b16) theorem $7.$

**Theorem $7$**. Let $(X,U)$ be a boundedly compact uniform space. Then the mapping $θ_I :(bs(X),U˜ ) → (K(X),U_H )$ is uniformly continuous.

***Proof:*** Let $U ∈ U$. Choose a $V ∈ U$ such that $V^3 ⊂ U.$ Let $((x_n), (y_n)) ∈ V˜$ and $p ∈ I(C_x)$ (where $x = (x_n)_{n∈N})$. Then $B =
\{n ∈ N: x_n ∈ V [p]\} \not∈ I$. Now for each $n ∈ B, (x_n, y_n) ∈ V$ and $(x_n, p) ∈ V$ so that $(y_n, p) ∈ V^ 2$, i.e. $y_n ∈ V^ 2[p]$. Hence

$\{n ∈ N: y_n ∈ V^2[p]\}⊃\{n ∈ N: x_n ∈ V [p]\}$

which implies that the set on the left hand side also cannot belong to $I$. Again as $V^2[p]$ is compact, by Theorem $6$, $V^ 2[p] ∩ I(C_y ) = ∅ (y = (y_n)_{n∈N})$. This implies that $p ∈ V^3[I(C_y)]$. Therefore
$$I(C_x) ⊂ V^3[I(C_y)]⊂U[I(C_y)].$$

Similarly it can be shown that $I(C_y ) ⊂ U[I(C_x)]$. Hence $(I(C_x),I(C_y)) ∈ U ∈ U_H$.

The point I have a problem is that I don't know what is meant by $V^3[I(C_y)]$ or $U[I(C_x)].$ If anybody explains that to me, may bay be I can do the rest. thank you.

Comment: Without reading the paper, I'll say those probably mean the uniform $V^3$-neighbourhood of $I(C_y)$ and the uniform $U$-neighbourhood of $I(C_x)$ respectively.

Comment: @DanielFischer: ok thanks. I'm reading the paper yet do not know- it is not mentioned anywhere. Perhaps the author expects that readers know it already.

Comment: Well, it's pretty standard notation when dealing with uniform spaces.

Comment: As Daniel Fischer said this notation is very likely as follows. Let $(X,\mathbb U)$ be a uniform space and $U\in\mathbb U$ be an entourage. For a point $p\in X$ we define $$U[p]=\{x\in X; (p,x)\in U\}.$$ In the case of metric spaces this is a ball of radius $U$ around the point $p$. This notation is also used in the Wikipedia article on [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space). In the paper it is introduced at the beginning of section 2.3.

Comment: For a subset $A\subseteq X$ we define
$$U[A] = \bigcup\limits_{a\in A} U[a] = \{x\in X; (\exists a\in A) (a,x)\in U\}.$$
Engelking calls this $U$-ball around $p$ and $U$-ball around $A$, although in Engelking's book the notation $B(p,U)$ and $B(A,U)$ is used, instead. (I do not definition $U[A]$ in the paper. Maybe I have missed it, maybe the author considered it to be standard enough to be omitted. It was not immediately clear to me - but I do not work with uniform spaces often.)